# $x_{n}$ is the unique solution of the equation $x+\cdots+x^{n}=1$ in $[0,1]$. How to find the equivalent infinitesimal of $x_{n}-1/2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$x_{n}$ is the unique solution of the equation $x+\cdots+x^{n}=1$ in $[0,1]$. It's easy to prove the limit of $x_{n}$ is $1/2$. I want to study the equivalent infinitesimal of $(x_{n}-1/2)$. But I have no idea. Any help will be thanked.

Comment: What notion of infinitesimals are you using?

Comment: You made my day with the problem and I thank you for that. May I confess that I have been surprised to see how good the approximations can be ? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x_n\in(1/2,1)$ and
$$0=x_n+\cdots+x_n^{n}-1=\sum_{k=1}^n(x_n^k-1/2^k)-\frac{1}{2^{n}}.$$
Hence, by the MVT, there are $t_2,\dots, t_n\in (1/2,x_n)\subset (1/2,1)$, such that
$$(x_n-1/2)\sum_{k=1}^nkt_k^{k-1}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$
and, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that
$$2^n(x_n-1/2)=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^nkt_k^{k-1}}\to \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k/2^{k-1}}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
Therefore 
$$x_n-1/2\sim\frac{1}{4\cdot 2^n}=\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.$$

Comment: You proved $x_n-\frac 12=O(\frac 1{2^n})$, but OP seems to be looking for an equivalent of $x_n-\frac 12$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon The same argument leads to equivalent infinitesimal.

Comment: How do you prove $\sum_{k=1}^nkt_k^{k-1}\to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k/2^{k-1}$ ? DCT ?

Comment: Yes, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}=1$$ so that

$$x-\frac12=\frac{x^{n+1}}2\approx\frac1{2^{n+2}}.$$

---

For better approximations write

$$\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)+\frac12\right)^{n+1}-2\left(x-\frac12\right)=0$$

and develop

$$\frac1{2^{n+1}}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n}}\left(x-\frac12\right)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2\cdot2^{n-1}}\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\cdots-2\left(x-\frac12\right)=0.$$

For small degrees, you obtain an analytical expression of the roots.

The first approximations are

$$x-\frac12=\frac1{2^{n+2}}$$

$$x-\frac12=\frac1{2^{n+2}-n-1}$$

$$x-\frac12=\frac1{2^{n+1}-n-1+\sqrt{(2^{n+1}-n-1)^2-2n(n+1)}}$$

Comment: Amazing problem, isn't it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: where there are Padé approximants, this is where fun is ;-)

Comment: May I confess a real passion for the $[1,k]$'s ?

Answer (score 3):

*May be another way to do it.*

Let $$y=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k-1$$ Expand as a series around $x=\frac 12$ to get
$$y=-2^{-n}+2^{1-n} \left(2^{n+1}-n-2\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+2^{1-n}
   \left(2^{n+2}-n^2-3n-4\right)
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Now, using series reversion
$$x-\frac 12=\frac{2^{n-1} \left(y+2^{-n}\right)}{2^{n+1}-n-2}-\frac{2^{2 n-2} \left(
   2^{n+2}-n^2-3n-4\right)
   \left(y+2^{-n}\right)^2}{\left(2^{n+1}-n-2\right)^3}+O\left(\left(y+2^{-n}
\right)^3\right)$$ that is to say
$$x-\frac 12=\frac{2^{n-1} \left(y+2^{-n}\right)}{2^{n+1}-n-2}+O\left(\left(y+2^{-n}
\right)^2\right)$$ 
 Making $y=0$ in the above expansion gives
$$x-\frac 12\sim\frac{1}{2 \left(2^{n+1}-n-2\right)}\tag 1$$ from which, as already given in answers,
$$x-\frac 12\sim\frac 1 {2^{n+2}}$$ The approximation given in $(1)$ seems to work quite well even for very small values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_{est}  & x_{sol} \\
 2 & 0.6250000000 &  0.6180339890 \\
 3 & 0.5454545455 &  0.5436890127 \\
 4 & 0.5192307692 &  0.5187900637 \\
 5 & 0.5087719298 &  0.5086603916 \\
 6 & 0.5041666667 &  0.5041382597 \\
 7 & 0.5020242915 &  0.5020170553 \\
 8 & 0.5009960159 &  0.5009941779 \\
 9 & 0.5004935834 &  0.5004931183 \\
 10 & 0.5002455796 &  0.5002454623
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We could even have a better approximation : after the series reversion, build the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant to get
$$x-\frac 12 \sim \frac{2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{2 n+3}-2^{n+3} n-3\ 2^{n+2}+n^2+5 n+4}\tag 2$$ Doing the same calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_{est}  & x_{sol} \\
 2 & 0.6176470588 &  0.6180339887 \\
 3 & 0.5436507937 &  0.5436890140 \\
 4 & 0.5187861272 &  0.5187900637 \\
 5 & 0.5086599818 &  0.5086603916 \\
 6 & 0.5041382164 &  0.5041382584 \\
 7 & 0.5020170510 &  0.5020170552 \\
 8 & 0.5009941775 &  0.5009941775 \\
 9 & 0.5004931183 &  0.5004931183 \\
 10 & 0.5002454623 &  0.5002454623
\end{array}
\right)$$